# If $u$ is harmonic, $\exists \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R},\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d,u(x) \leq \alpha |x|+\beta,$ then $u$ is affine

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, harmonic-functions

We consider a harmonic function $u:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ $(\Delta u=0).$ Suppose that $$\exists \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R},\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d,u(x)\leq \alpha |x|+\beta.$$

Therefore $u-u(0)$ is linear: $$\exists\lambda\in \mathbb{R}^d,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d,u(x)=\langle\lambda,x\rangle+u(0)$$

I am looking for a ***probabilistic proof of this fact***

We note that Liouville's theorem for bounded harmonic functions is a particular case, where we can use Ito's formula, martingale convergence and Blumenthal's $0$-$1$ law to prove it.

***How to use probabilistic techniques to prove the above claim? (To be noted that it's sufficient to prove that partial derivatives of $u$ are constant)***

Other proofs are also appreciated.

Comment: Do you assume only a one-side estimate?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: See Theorem II here for a quick proof by hand: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-102-04/S0002-9939-1988-0934865-6/S0002-9939-1988-0934865-6.pdf (This does not literally apply to your setting since your bound is not a polynomial, but for example one can use the result to conclude that $u$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ and then prove the full statement.)

Comment: this site is more about research questions. For textbook exercises it is better to post in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you downvote and vote to close the question? Already did post an easier version of the above on mathstackexchange with no answer! Also, the question is related to research, in case you didn't notice the question in the textbook isn't asking for a probabilistic proof, the given hint is purely analytic! I was curious and my interest was to know if we can prove it using tools from probability and stochastic calculus. Anyone who works in the domain would confirm this is a research question. So, are you still convinced this is not a research question?!

Comment: See this for a neat proof, though purely analytic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508973/how-to-prove-a-harmonic-function-is-a-polynomial

Comment: @mathex cross-posting is not encouraged unless at least a week passes by. It is good to include the link from your other post to prevent people from doing double work. Here it is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751896/if-u-is-harmonic-exists-alpha-beta-in-mathbbr-forall-x-in-mathbbr

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard exercise eg. see
["Harmonic Function bounded by a linear function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395708/harmonic-function-bounded-by-a-linear-function) where a similar proof works here too. It is immediate using the Cauchy-estimate.

In terms of probabilistic proof, at least we get to use Liouville theorem which has probabilistic proof. But I doubt one can do be better since one needs to deal with derivatives and the Cauchy-estimate.

As mentioned in the comments we will follow the hint of the exercise 4 4.8 in [Brownian Motion and Classical Potential Theory by M.Rao (1977)](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/rao4.pdf) via the mean value property.

To be clear the author made a typo that he corrected in his picture i.e. $A_{t}=B_{R-t}(x+th)$ and not $A_{t}=B_{R}(x+th)$. We again let $A:=B_{R}(x)$. Therefore

$$\frac{u(x+th)-u(x)}{t}=\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{|A_{t}|}\int_{A_{t}}u(y)dy-\frac{1}{|A|}\int_{A}u(y)dy\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{|A_{t}|}-\frac{1}{|A|}\right)\int_{A_{t}}u(y)dy-\frac{1}{t|A|}\int_{A\setminus A_{t}}u(y)dy.$$

We have $|A_{t}|=c(R-t)^{2}$ and $|A|=cR^{2}$. We use the bound on the second term and mean-value on the first

$$\geq \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{|A_{t}|}-\frac{1}{|A|}\right)|A_{t}|u(x+th)-\frac{1}{t|A|}\int_{A\setminus A_{t}}\alpha |y|+\beta dy.$$

The first term we just a derivative in $t$. For the second term, we use $\int_{A}|y|=c_{n}R^{3}=|A|R$. After taking $t\to 0$ we are left with
$$\geq c_{1}\frac{u(x)}{R}-c_{2}\alpha.$$

By taking $R\to +\infty$, we get that the partial derivative is lower bounded. Since it is also harmonic, we can apply Liouville (["An entire function whose real part is bounded above must be constant."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229312/an-entire-function-whose-real-part-is-bounded-above-must-be-constant) for $Ref=-\partial_{h} u$).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I know that. But I veered a bit away. Is my proof wrong though? I couldn't see what he meant by lower bound because we only have an upper bound on u(x).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune ok i will go fix it now. thank you.